# Not able to install AppiumLibrary with robotframework in jython

Tags: python, jython, robotframework, python-appium

I am trying to install AppiumLibrary with robotframework in jython

Steps followed:

```
jython -m pip install robotframework-appiumLibrary
```

Error:

```
Downloading/unpacking sauceclient>=0.1.0 (from robotframework-appiumLibrary)
  Downloading sauceclient-0.2.1.tar.gz

  Running setup.py (path:C:\Users\ABHISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_abhishek
singh\sauceclient\setup.py) egg_info for package sauceclient

  Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\ABHISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_abhisheksingh\saucecl
ient\setup.py", line 27, in <module>

  from sauceclient import __version__

  File "sauceclient.py", line 26, in <module>

   is_py2 = sys.version_info.major is 2
    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 17, in <module>

  File "C:\Users\ABHISH~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip_build_abhisheksingh\sauceclient
\setup.py", line 27, in <module>

from sauceclient import __version__
 File "sauceclient.py", line 26, in <module>

   is_py2 = sys.version_info.major is 2

**AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'major'**
```

Anybody has any idea how to use this libaray?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to debug sauceclient-0.2.1.tar.gz. See if you can install it before installing robotframework-appiumLibrary. 
To fix the code in "sauceclient.py" edit to:

```
is_py2 = sys.version_info[0] is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much ,it did work for me here are the steps I followed:

1.Download sauceclient-0.2.1 and Changed sauceclient.py

```
is_py2 = sys.version_info[0] is 2
```

2. Install sauceclient-0.2.1

jython -m setup.py install

3.Run :
jython -m pip install robotframework-appiumLibrary